# why can claim variables in same name?

Tags: java

Java does not allow same type variable with same names.

Like this code will have an error message: "Duplicate local variable"

```
public class test123 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int a=1;
      int a=1;
    }  
}
```

but for this code, "int a"  is claimed in the while loop three times(because this while loop run 3 times, so "int a" is claimed for 3 times also),

why the compiler allow it to pass compile?

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {  
    int i=3;
    while (i>0) {
      int a=1;
      System.out.println("1");  
      i--;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The scope of the loop resets each iteration, so `a` is removed from the stack and able to be declared again.

Note: this **is** valid, and maybe what you wanted.

```
int a = 1;
a = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

"Variable declaration" happens at compile time, not at run time. Even if you declare a variable within a loop, the variable is declared only once.

At run time, only one copy of your variable "a" exists, and it's neither created nor destroyed during the loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

There is totally 4 sope of a variable.

**Class scope:** The variable those defined as static are called class level variables and it will be created only once for a particular class and the same will be used throughout the life of that class.

**Instance scope:** These the variable which is defined as non-ststic at the class level. The scope of the variable if for that particular instance. If you create 2 instances of a class than each instance will have there own variables and storage.

**Local scope:** These variables are defined inside the method or as a parameter of a method. The scope of these variables is for that method only. It can't be accessed outside the method.

**Block scope:** These variables are defined inside a particular block (if, while, for, switch etc) in a method. And the variable is accessed only inside that block, it will be assessable outside that block.

In your case the variable `i` is a local variable so it will be available for that particular method. variable `a` is a block variable and the scope of that variable if only for that while loop single iteration. Once one it starts executing the while loop, it will create the variable `a` and once the execution of the first iteration finished than it will destroy that variable. SO in the next iteration again the same process will be followed.